# ng-options default option object is not selecting with an array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have a array of objects like following, I would like show in select tag using ng-options.

1. I have to show country name as display name
2. I have compulsory Store selected 'object' in model option

for default option

In controller

```
$scope.selectedCountry = {"US":"United States"}
$scope.countries: [
   {"name":"United States", code: "US"},
   {"name":"Canada", code: "US"},
   {"name":"Afghanistan", code: "US"},
   {"name":"Albania", code: "US"},
   {"name":"Algeria", code: "US"},
   {"name":"American Samoa", code: "US"},
      .....
   ];
```

In html page:

```
ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries track by country"
```

It is  not selecting default object

can you please suggest what is wrong ?

Thanks in Advance,
Prasad.

Comment: Note that your country codes are all the same. That might cause problems if you select by country code.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the default like this:

```
$scope.countries= [
   {"name":"United States", code: "US"},
   {"name":"Canada", code: "C"},
   {"name":"Afghanistan", code: "A"},
   {"name":"Albania", code: "AL"},
   {"name":"Algeria", code: "AG"},
   {"name":"American Samoa", code: "AS"}
];
$scope.selectedCountry = $scope.countries[1]; //Select Canada
```

Also you need to remove the track by.

Here you have a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/kkq0Fy4NCfBIa0Ioy8En?p=preview

Also here you have another example if you prefer selecting by country code (wich seems cleaner to me):

http://plnkr.co/edit/TaCcpgtMLYFvzQqcdGKS?p=preview

Comment: Hi Alfonso Presa , Shall I know difference b/w $scope.selectedCountry = $scope.countries[1] and  $scope.selectedCountry = {"US":"United States"};

Comment: In edit mode also we get that value from database or some api, how can we handle that situation, please explain. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First of all ng-options performs a '===' comparision, so if you use an object they should be the same one (https://jsfiddle.net/fk4uLw56/). Also note that {US:"United States"} doesn't even have the same content as {name:"UnitedStates", code:"US"}.

Comment: $scope.selectedCountry = {"name":"United States", code: "US"}; this one also not working in http://plnkr.co/edit/kkq0Fy4NCfBIa0Ioy8En?p=preview

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'edit mode' and how it is related to the original question. Any way, if you mean that you get {"US":"United States"} as input, then you can do this to get the code and then follow the seconds example in the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/qfx2km63/

Comment: Have you checked the working examples I have posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87950/discussion-between-durga-prasad-and-alfonso-presa).